# How could the USS Bozeman be in the Typhon Expanse?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, timeline

In *Cause and Effect* (S5:E18), Picard's Captain's Log states they are charting the Typhon Expanse and the *Enterprise-D* is "the first Starfleet vessel to chart this unexplored region". This implies it's in one of the more remote regions of Federation space or even outside of the Federation in "International Space" or extremely difficult to navigate to.

Yet the *Bozeman* was there in the Typhon Expanse but 80-90 years prior to the 24th century. Further, they were only 3 weeks away from their starbase. This is right next door to the Expanse in galactic terms. It seems unlikely in the span of 100 years or however long that starbase has been operational that Starfleet hadn't gone as far as 3 weeks away. (This assumes it took the *Bozeman* the full 3 weeks to get to the TE and they just got there.)

**How can the *USS Bozeman* be in the Thyphon Expanse when Picard says the *Enterprise-D* is "the first Starfleet vessel to chart this unexplored region"?**

Comment: Picard *believes* the Enterprise-D is first *known* Starfleet vessel in that region.

Comment: Oha just found a question that  COULD answer yours oO.  Can you please check if that sufficiently explains it? If not I would say please reformulate (so that the difference is clear) as the answer sounds very answering there. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73139/why-was-there-apparently-no-knowledge-of-the-missing-ship-in-the-typhon-expanse?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy. Especially if you keep two things in mind. First is that federation ships are shown time and again to have some freedom with interpreting their non-war orders. Thus the Bozeman could have been assigned to the general sector, but not in special to research the expanse. And they just thought when we are here we could also do that.

The second is... Picard is correct. The Bozeman was either assigned to the sector or to research the expanse itself. But it never returned. Presumably a few ships searched for her but she remained disappeared. So it is quite possible that "no Federation ship ever charted that region". As we know one did but it never came back to say "we did".